# jQuery -- CORS and Headers (Tastypie)

Tags: jquery, tastypie, cors

I'm accessing an API via a CORS request.  The API response for create sets a 'Location' header of the newly created resource.  I am unable to access this via jQuery's xhr object.

```
var location = xhr.getResponseHeader( 'Location' ); // returns null
```

The server sets the proper cross site header that I know of:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Location
```

Any help?  I have access to the API so can update any headers necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm the CORS POST request was successful? Using Chrome Inspector or Firebug in Firefox what does the response look like? Are you getting a 201 HTTP code back?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is I was sending the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` which if I understand correctly specifies which headers the client is going to send to the server in the request.  I instead added `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` which specifies which headers in the response the client is allowed to see and it worked.